# count the number of null fields in every row in Access (not by query)

Tags: ms-access, field

I have designed a database using access.

How do I count the number of fields every row in Access  (not by query)?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is almost incomprehensible. Please show some example data and the expected result. [ask]

Comment: thanks you. i want to count numbers null fields every records.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way having your DAO.Recordset `rs` located on a valid record:

```
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim Nulls As Integer

For Each fld In rs.Field
    ' Count Null values.
    Nulls = Nulls + Abs(IsNull(fld.Value))
Next
```

Comment: thanks you very much

Comment: Where do I use of this code

Comment: You will use it at that point in your application where you, not using a query, wish to count the fields holding Null.